# Edge requires re-dispositioning before item responds to target events

Tags: css, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I've got a modal with a bunch of list items with checkboxes. When the check boxes are clicked the item disappears. In Chrome and Firefox it makes it quite easy to move through a long list of them by clicking one checkbox after another very quickly. In Edge, however, the item that is replacing the item that disappears doesn't register as being a `hover` item until i move my mouse again. Is there some fix for this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a repro of the issue, this can be any number of issues relating to hit testing, painting or style calc issues. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Forgive me for having to ask- what is the best way to provide such a thing?

Comment: No problem, you can utilize a site such as https://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/?html,output - whichever you prefer, and try to provide as little code as possible but still shows the problem.